# adding and manipulating a div via jquery, without using any html like code

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have an odd question, I know, but is there a way to adding a div element to a specific element without write any html code in the javascript function?

what I mean is:

I normally use this:

```
  $(".divclass").append("<div>Test</div>");
```

but this is easy to "read", i would like something like:

```
  $(".divcalss").append(newDiv.text( "Test");
```

I would like to have NO HTML inside the javascript, i can achieve it when I manipulate css, or attributes, or many other thigs... but is there a way to this to add a div?

thanks in advance.

Comment: `var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); $(newDiv).text('asd').appendTo('.divclass')`???

Comment: aaaaaah this is perfect, thanks, if you write the answer, i'll acept asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new DOM element with something like:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
```

This then becomes a document fragment until it's inserted into the document (or your specified element) with some JS:

```
var myElement = document.getElementById('myElement');
myElement.appendChild(div);
```

If you'd rather us jQuery for the insertion:

```
$('#myElement').append(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try document.createElement.

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div'); 
$(newDiv).text('asd').appendTo('.divclass')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an HTML element by using document.createElement().

Try this:

```
function addElement() {
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
    newdiv.innerHTML = 'Test';

    $(".divclass").append(newdiv);
}
```

You can add attributes with the following method:

```
newdiv.setAttribute('id', 'newdiv');
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you would like something that is reusable:

```
$.fn.appendNew = function() {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    var $el = $(el); 
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).append(el);
    });
    return $el;
}

$('p').appendNew().text('world').css('color', 'red');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LKZTC/1/